# Meaning of 'earth'

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

> It is in vain to say human beings ought to be satisfied with tranquillity: they must have action; and they will make it if they cannot find it. Millions are condemned to a stiller doom than mine, and millions are in silent revolt against their lot. Nobody knows how many rebellions besides political rebellions ferment in the masses of life which people **earth**. (Jane Eyre)

I can’t find any relevant meaning in the dictionaries for *earth*. Is it a verb? If it is, what does it mean? If not, what does 'which people earth' mean?

Comment: For more-general interpretive remarks (not answering your specific question) on the passage, also see [sparknotes](http://www.sparknotes.com/lit/janeeyre/quotes.html#explanation4)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It’s the noun which describes the planet on which we live, and it’s the object of the verb *people*, which here means ‘populate’. It is possible to omit the definite article in contexts such as this.

**EDIT:** FumbleFingers provides an alternative reading which deserves serious consideration.

Comment: Aw shucks, I was hoping this was going to be a question about the UK usage of *earthed* from electronics, for the same thing that North Americans use *grounded* for.

Comment: @Barrie England Is this a standard and modern English or an obsolete usage of English considering the time of story?

Comment: @user37324. The absence of the definite article before 'Earth' might be now be found only in literary contexts. In normal usage, we might be more inclined to talk about, for example, 'the Earth's population', rather than use a verb phrase.

Comment: @Barrie: Think again. Brontë is a very precise writer, and grammatically I don't see how you can parse this one as a noun usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Grammatically it would fit either way. I would agree that the verb construction is correct (though I never read it that way before), but to state that it cannot be parsed as a noun is wrong. Re-read it as "the masses who populate the Earth" and you will see where Barrie is coming from. (A reading made easier, at least for me, by the repeated reference to "millions".)

Comment: @Jonathan: If you discard the syntactically irrelevant *Nobody knows how many* and *besides political rebellions*, you're left with *Rebellions ferment in the masses of life which people earth*. It's totally impossible to parse "earth" as anything other than a verb, even if you think you can still derive some "meaning" from the words.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why not?  People means populate.  "...the masses of life which populate [the] earth."  At that time, Earth was not always capitalized, and the article was often omitted in (what the OED refers to as) poetic and rhetorical uses.

Comment: @snailplane: oic. I discarded that interpretation initially because it seemed inconceivable to me that Brontë would refer to *people* as *"**masses** [i.e. - **lumps**] of life"*, but I suppose it is at least "credible". I still don't really buy it though. Particularly since she goes on to say *[women need] a field for their efforts*, which I see as echoing the "horticultural/agricultural" sense of "earthing up" rebellion. But I do agree that your interpretation isn't affected by *earth* being uncapitalised, and having no article.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't mean to say your interpretation is wrong, by the way.  I just wanted to argue that both are grammatically possible.

Comment: @snailplane: Right. I have to say I wouldn't like to bet the farm on either interpretation. I freely admit my reason for initially discarding the *human beings are "masses of life"* was just that I thought it was far too modern/quirky/flippant for Brontë. But maybe there's some subtle reason connected with language change why it would have come across differently 150 years ago.

Answer (score 7):

It's a *very* obscure (and I would say, archaic) ***verb*** usage. Relevant definitions from OED include:

> To bury (a corpse);
>    To plunge or hide (something) in the earth;
>    *trans. Hort.* To heap the earth over (the roots and stems of plants), esp. in order to prevent the greening of potato tubers, or to blanch the stems of leeks, celery, etc.

Jane (or more properly, Charlotte Brontë) is portraying [social *and* political] rebellion as  [an inevitable upswelling of a homogeneous animal life-force](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DUbmZH8Tok0C&pg=PA21&dq=%22masses%20of%20life%20which%20people%20earth%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8vE9UeSsB46A7QbN24CQDQ&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22masses%20of%20life%20which%20people%20earth%22&f=false) that "grows" in people the way vegetables grow in earth. She's saying that "the people" collectively not only *bury/hide* rebellion "beneath the surface"; they're also *nurturing and protecting* rebellion until it sprouts fully-formed into the visible world we actually perceive.

Comment: That’s certainly a possible interpretation, and one which the Harold Bloom reference seems to support.

Comment: @Barrie: I wouldn't want to be too dogmatic in saying exactly what Brontë *means* by the word "earth" here (that's basically Lit Crit, and Off Topic anyway). But I don't see how we can avoid accepting that it's a ***verb*** usage.

Comment: To read _earth_ as a verb requires us to understand _rebellions_ as the antecedent of _which_. In that case, she would be saying _people earth rebellions_. As I said, that does seem to be a possible reading, but, if that is what she meant, she wasn’t being particularly helpful to the reader, who will normally take the relative pronoun as referring to the nearest preceding noun phrase, which, in this case, is _the masses of life_, and is the subject of _peoples_.

Comment: @Barrie: I see your point. But I have to say if I parse *people* as the verb, that leaves me with *the masses of life* being the things which populate *[the] Earth*. Effectively, *masses of life = human beings*, which strikes me as a really clinical/dismissive type of reference that I find hard to square with the overall tone of the excerpt.

Comment: I had a hard time with this idea, mainly due to the explanation of growing and vegetable gardens. However, the image of a heaping mass and fermentation is very easy to conceive of as a metaphor for composting...

Comment: @horatio: Aristotle was prepared to believe life [arose spontaneously out of mud](http://www.yale.edu/ynhti/curriculum/units/1980/5/80.05.11.x.html), and most Victorians would either go with that or assume "God" made/makes life. I see it as a metaphoric "creating life/giving birth" usage. Composting is more about recycling dead organisms for re-consumption by now-living ones.

Comment: I think it self-evident that fermentation requires pre-existing organisms.